# QPID JMS Heartbeat / Keepalive

Tags: jms, qpid

is it possible to set a heartbeat or keep-alive for a JMS consumer using QPID JMS? I've found some configuration of QPID which can bet set at the URL like an idleTimeout but I've not found an option to send empty frames for a limited time period.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Qpid JMS client allows you to configure how long the idle timeout is which controls when the client will consider the remote to have failed should there be no traffic coming from the remote either in the form of messages or possibly as empty frames in order to keep the connection from idling out.  The client will itself respond the the remote peer's requested idle timeout interval by sending as needed an empty frame to ensure that the remote doesn't drop the connection due to inactivity.

If you are seeing drops in connections due to idle timeout on a server then it is likely you have not configured the server to provide an Idle timeout value in the Open performative that it sends to the client.

Reading the specification section on [Idle Timeout of a Connection](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/amqp-core-transport-v1.0-os.html#doc-doc-idle-time-out) can shed some light on how this works.